# how do I start multiple services in a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, supervisord

I have a running container but I am starting few services manually. The services are :

```
service httpd start
service postgresql start
service vpms start
```

So, how do I start the container without starting my services manually? I don't have any Dockerfile as of now. Any examples of how to start these services would definitely help

Comment: So this is an anti-pattern for docker as in general services and containers should be one to one. It is possible though if your process to which the container's lifespan is attached is, say, a shell script that starts and monitors these other services. But again, try to consider containers as services, not virtual machines

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, you probably want to look at docker swarm services:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/deploy-service/

I like to use portainer to admin swarm services:

https://github.com/portainer/portainer

But you could also use it to manage other kinds of deployments, including local ones.

If you are just running locally, maybe you're happy firing them up individually:

```
docker run --name=postgres ... postgres
docker run --link postgres:postgres --name=myapp ... myapp
docker run --link myapp:myapp ... nginx
```

Then inside your 'myapp' container you can ping postgres and use it as your DB host.  And inside your nginx container you can ping myapp and refer to it to forward http requests.